# How to properly deal with errors while using NodeJS's readline module

Tags: node.js, async-await

I am attempting to read and process a file line by line. I would like to use try / catch async pattern to do this.  Below is an example lifted directly from NodeJS docs on how to use readline module.

```
const { once } = require('events');
const { createReadStream } = require('fs');
const { createInterface } = require('readline');

(async function processLineByLine() {
  try {
    const rl = createInterface({
      input: createReadStream('big-file.txt'),
      crlfDelay: Infinity
    });

    rl.on('line', (line) => {
      // Process the line.
    });

    await once(rl, 'close');

    console.log('File processed.');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

The `await once` part is throwing me through a loop I think.  What I want to do if I encounter an error while parsing the line:

```
    rl.on('line', (line) => {
    try {
      // Process the line. maybe error from parsing?
      JSON.parse(line) 
    } catch ( error ) {
      throw new Error("error while attempting to process json.")
    }

    });
```

Is have access to that newly thrown error in the outer try / catch block like:

```
    console.log('File processed.');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    // should see "error while attempting to process json."
  }
})();
```

So far the firebase function crashes without ever reaching the outer try / catch block. I've tried adding error event listeners to the readline stream like:

```
rl.on("error", () => { // throw error here })
```

with no success.

Answer (score 1):

try/catch only catch synchrone errors. So it won't catch anything from inside `rl.on()`. Doing `await once()` just await the stream rl before to execute the `console.log('File processed.');` but the `try{}catch(e){}` has already been executed so any err can't be catch.

`rl.on('error', () => {}` will only catch the error from the rl stream itself, so even if an error occur at `createReadStream('big-file.txt')` it won't be catch (and as it is async the final catch(e) won t catch it neither).

To catch any error which occured in `rl.on('line ....'`, one of the solutions is to reject the error. A rejected error into an async/await func will be catch() like in an synchrone flow.

an Exemple

```
  async function processLineByLine() {
            try{                   
    
                    async function run() {          
                            const rs = createReadStream(__filename)
                            // otherwise createReadStream() err are not handled
                            rs.on('error', () => {          
                                console.log('HandleReadStreanErr')
                            })     
    
                            const rl = createInterface({    
                              input: rs,                      
                              crlfDelay: Infinity             
                            })
                            
                            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                            rl.on('line', (line) => {       
                                 try {                           
                                    throw new Error("error while attempting to process json.")
                                    resolve(console.log(line.toString()))
    
                                 } catch(e) {                    
                                    reject(e)                       
                                 }                               
    
                            })
                            })
                            
                            // handle specificaly the rl stream error
                            rl.on('error', () => console.log('errr rl stream'))
      
    
                            await once(rl, 'close');        
                            console.log('File processed.'); 
                    }
                    // await the overall execution for the catch() to wait
                    await run()
            
        } catch(e) {
                    // only rejected err reach here or the one happening synchronously
                    console.error('eeeeeee')        
        }
    }
processLineByLine()
```

I personally like to handle each err close to where they occur. But some persons like to handle them at a single place with an err handler. In this case we can wrap the overall execution with a promise

```
 async function processLineByLine() {
        try{
        
           async function run() {
        
            return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        
                const rs = createReadStream('khg.jk')
                rs.on('error', () => {
                    reject('HandleReadStreanErr')
                })
        
                const rl = createInterface({
                  input: rs,
                  crlfDelay: Infinity
                })
        
                rl.on('line', (line) => {
                     try {
                        // uncomment following err
                        // throw new Error("error while attempting to process json.")
                        resolve(console.log(line.toString()))
        
                     } catch(e) {
                        reject(e)
                     }
        
                })
        
                rl.on('error', () => reject('errr rl stream'))
        
        
                await once(rl, 'close');
                console.log('File processed.');
        
            })
           }
           await run()
        
           } catch(e) {
                console.error('set error handler: ', e)
           }
   }
   processLineByLine()
```